# Deleting Inline Images from Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

The requirement is to remove attachments from Outlook email. Here is the code:

```
internal void ClearAttachments()
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Globals.ThisAddin.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem as MailItem;
        try
        {
            if (mailItem != null && mailItem.Attachments.Count >= 1 )
            {
                for (int i = mailItem.Attachments.Count; i >= 1; i--)
                {
                    mailItem.Attachments[i].Delete();
                    mailItem.Attachments.Remove(i);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //log this if needed.
        }
```

It works perfectly fine for most commonly used files except "inline-images" it does not identify them as attachment if I have less than 3 inline-images (strange!) but works fine if I have inline-images and other files (eg. txt) in this case when is is removed Outlook still shows a rectangular block (sort of container) while the image is removed.

Comment: How are attachments represented in the HTML markup? Are they referenced using the `cid:` attribite or 64-bits encoded?

Comment: mailItem.HTMLBody property suggests following: 
            <span style='mso-no-proof:yes'><img width=657 height=232 id=\"Picture_x0020_1\" src=\"cid:image001.png@01D0EAE4.A98A98A0\"></span>
            <o:p></o:p>

Comment: You need to get the correspoding attached image file with the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E") set to image001.png@01D0EAE4.A98A98A0 as the HTML markup shows.

Answer (score 0):

The rectangular block is shown by the HTML body that now refers to an image that no longer exists. You need to also update the MailItem.HTMLBody property appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but when there are in-line images, mailItem.Attachments does not reflect them. If I have 3 inline images, the mailItem.Attachments.Count is still 0.

Comment: If the images are referenced by a remote url instead of cid attribute, of course the Attachments collection will not have them - they only exist on a remote server. You will need to process the HTMLBody property and delete the img tags that you do not want.